# PySpark - Conditional Create Column with GroupBy

Tags: python, apache-spark, if-statement, pyspark, group-by

I need to create an indicator for each ID based a date condition using a second pyspark dataframe.

The indicator is 1 or 0, which tells me a sensor failed. The indicator is conditional on a second dataframe that has the first failure date and the last failure date. If the failure was recorded in `fail_df`, `main_df` rows should have a 1 on and between the first and last recorded failure from `fail_df`. When the sensor didn't fail within the `main_df` dates, it should store a value of 0.

**main_df DataFrame**

```
ID         |  Date      |Value 
-------------------------------------------------
P1         | 2016-10-01 |100
P1         | 2016-10-02 |200
P1         | 2016-12-16 |700
P1         | 2016-12-17 |800
P1         | 2016-12-18 |800
P2         | 2016-01-31 |700
P2         | 2016-02-01 |800
P2         | 2016-02-02 |900
```

**Failure List DataFrame**

```
ID         |  First Fail Date      | Last Fail Date
-----------------------------------------------------
P1         | 2016-10-01            |2016-10-02  |
P2         | 2016-01-31            |2016-02-01  |
```

**Desired DataFrame**

```
ID         |  Date      |Value  | Failure_Indicator     
-------------------------------------------------
P1         | 2016-10-01 |100    | 1
P1         | 2016-10-02 |200    | 1
P1         | 2016-12-16 |700    | 0
P1         | 2016-12-17 |800    | 0
P1         | 2016-12-18 |800    | 0
P2         | 2016-01-31 |700    | 1
P2         | 2016-02-01 |800    | 1
P2         | 2016-02-02 |900    | 0
```

**What I have tried:
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'withColumn'**

```
df = main_df.groupBy('ID').withColumn(
    'Failure_Indicator',
    F.when((fail_df.col("First fail Date") >= main_df.Date) & 
           (fail_df.col("Last fail Date") >= main_df.Date), 1)
     .otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_1=spark.createDataFrame([("P1", "2016-10-01", 100), ("P1", "2016-10-03", 200), ("P3", "2016-10-09", 200)], ["id", "date", "value"])

+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
| P1|2016-10-01|  100|
| P1|2016-10-03|  200|
| P3|2016-10-09|  200|
+---+----------+-----+

df_2=spark.createDataFrame([("P1", "2016-10-01", "2016-10-02")], ["id", "start_date", "end_date"])

+---+----------+----------+
| id|start_date|  end_date|
+---+----------+----------+
| P1|2016-10-01|2016-10-02|
+---+----------+----------+


df_1.join(df_2, 'id', 'left_outer') \
    .withColumn('failure_indicator', when((col("date") >= col("start_date")) & (col("date") <= col("end_date")), 1).otherwise(0)) \
    .select('id', 'date', 'value', 'failure_indicator') \
    .show()

+---+----------+-----+-----------------+
| id|      date|value|failure_indicator|
+---+----------+-----+-----------------+
| P3|2016-10-09|  200|                0|
| P1|2016-10-01|  100|                1|
| P1|2016-10-03|  200|                0|
+---+----------+-----+-----------------+
```